# Profile a rails controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way to profile a controller action in Ruby on Rails. Currently I am using the brute-force method of throwing in `puts Time.now` calls between what I think will be a bottleneck. But that feels really, really dirty. There has got to be a better way.

Answer (score 44):

I picked up this technique a while back and have found it quite handy.

When it's in place, you can add `?profile=true` to any URL that hits a controller. Your action will run as usual, but instead of delivering the rendered page to the browser, it'll send a detailed, nicely formatted ruby-prof page that shows where your action spent its time.

First, add ruby-prof to your Gemfile, probably in the development group:

```
group :development do
    gem "ruby-prof"
end
```

Then add an [around filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#after-filters-and-around-filters) to your ApplicationController:

```
around_action :performance_profile if Rails.env == 'development'

def performance_profile
  if params[:profile] && result = RubyProf.profile { yield }

    out = StringIO.new
    RubyProf::GraphHtmlPrinter.new(result).print out, :min_percent => 0
    self.response_body = out.string

  else
    yield
  end
end
```

Reading the ruby-prof output is a bit of an art, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

**Additional note by ScottJShea:**
If you want to change the measurement type place this:

`RubyProf.measure_mode = RubyProf::GC_TIME #example`

Before the `if` in the profile method of the application controller. You can find a list of the available measurements at the [ruby-prof page](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof#measurements). As of this writing the `memory` and `allocations` data streams seem to be corrupted ([see defect](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof/issues/86)).

Comment: for anyone cun'n'pasting this, you also need to add "require 'ruby-prof'" at the top of your ApplicationController. Also, for me, I had to alter "self.response_body=" to "self.response.body=" (Rails 2.3.14)

Comment: Thanks for those tweaks. `response_body` was added in Rails 3.0. And if you're using bundler, you shouldn't need to require ruby-prof, but I'm glad that this technique was pretty adaptable to an older version of Rails.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Pavling. I'm also using rails 2.3.14, and having trouble getting this to work. I get "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)" in graph_html_printer.rb:98:in `full_name', no matter what version of ruby-prof I install. Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: To get this to override the return format for JSON, XML, and so on, add this to the if statement: `headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html"`

Answer (score 9):

Use the Benchmark standard library and the various tests available in Rails (unit, functional, integration). Here's an example:

```
def test_do_something
  elapsed_time = Benchmark.realtime do
    100.downto(1) do |index|
      # do something here
    end
  end
  assert elapsed_time < SOME_LIMIT
end
```

So here we just do something 100 times, time it via the Benchmark library, and ensure that it took less than SOME_LIMIT amount of time.

You also may find these links useful: The [Benchmark.realtime reference](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/classes/Benchmark.html#M000011) and the [Test::Unit reference](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/classes/Test/Unit.html). Also, if you're into the 'book reading' thing, I picked up the idea for the example from [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails2/agile-web-development-with-rails), which talks all about the different testing types and a little on performance testing.

Comment: This answer tells you how to make sure your action is running quickly enough.  It doesn't help you with profiling, which is finding out which part of the action is taking the most time.

Answer (score 9):

There's a Railscast on profiling that's well worth watching

http://railscasts.com/episodes/98-request-profiling

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give the [FiveRuns TuneUp](http://www.fiveruns.com/products/tuneup) service a try, as it's really rather impressive. *Disclaimer: I'm not associated with FiveRuns in any way, I've just tried this service out.*

TuneUp is a free service whereby you download a plugin and when you run your application it injects a panel at the top of the screen that can be expanded to display detailed performance metrics.

It gives you some nice graphs, including one that shows what proportion of time is spent in the Model, View and Controller. You can even drill right down to see the individual SQL queries that ActiveRecord is executing if you need to and it can show you the underlying database schema with another click.

Finally, you can optionally upload your profiling data to the FiveRuns site for community performance analysis and advice.

Comment: Link is broken (DNS expired).

Answer (score -1):

This works in Rails 4.2.6:

```
    o=OpenStruct.new(logger: Rails.logger)
    o.extend ActiveSupport::Benchmarkable
    o.benchmark 'name' do
      # ... your code ...
    end
```

Comment: This does not display anything on the logs or elsewhere.