# Benchmarking controller + view together, many times in one go

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, benchmarking

I am learning how to benchmark two implementations in the controller/view. They are doing th e same thing, but one is done in view and another in controller. The code is shown below. My questions are:

1. is it possible to measure the taken for the same action to render 100 times in one go?
2. is my current benchmarking correctly measuring the combination of view + controller times?
3. is there any better way to do this?

```

```
  def sort_in_view
    self.class.benchmark("$sort in view") do
      @regions = Region.all

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
      end
    end
  end

  def sort_in_controller
    self.class.benchmark("$sort in controller") do
      @regions = {}
      Region.all.each do |r|
        @regions[r] = r.countries.order_by_name
      end

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320/how-to-profile-a-rails-controller-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run each case many times to get a more accurate average, I used Apache Benchmark at the end.

```
ab -c 1 -n 100 http://example.com/regions
```

This will run the request 100 times (with concurrency of 1), and give you a detailed summary of the mean and percentiles. I benchmark against my local machine, and it saves time since no browser rendering is required.

Answer (score 0):

see benchmaek results,just see your Rails log